# GRE Math Bible question No. 29 on Page-98: Why can't $x/2 = 2y/3 = z$ be considered as another correct answer?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Take a look at the [question No. 29 on Page-98](https://greworldknowlegde.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/nova-gre-math-bible.pdf).

> 29. Which one of the following is true regarding the triangle shown in figure?
>
> (A)  $x > y > z$
>
> (B)  $x < y < z $
>
> (C)  $x = y = z$
>
> (D)  $2x = 3y/2 = z$
>
> (E)  $x/2 = 2y/3 = z$
>
> [image]

The given answer is

> **(A) x > y > z**. (See Page-146)

But,

Why can't **(E)** be considered as another correct answer?

Comment: Sadly, the ratio of angles is not, in general, the ratio of the sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because angles are NOT proportional to their opposite sides. Their sines are, but not the angles themselves.